# Git Merge: how to do a new commit ONLY if differences happen in different files

Tags: git, merge

Here is my problem. for example,

```
 A---B---C topic
     /
D---E---F---G master
```

The content of `fileA` on `E` commit (common ancestor of topic and master) is:

```
abc def
```

`fileA` on the `topic` branch is :

```
abc def
abc
```

`fileA` on the `master` branch is :

```
abc def
abc
gh  //added by master.
```

When doing "`git checkout master; git merge topic`", a new `fileA` would be got:

```
abc def
abc
gh
```

But I do not want this happen, if it get differences on any 2 files on the merge branches, I want git to quit and throw me a error message or something like that.

Thanks for  VonC's editing and answer. I would notice the question format next time:).

**But if someone else changed another files in topic ,while not changed in master since commit E, i could allow it merge into my branch.I may not express it clearly before**

Why I need this?
Because I just want to make sure my patch will produce "my own" changes compared with my original `fileA`  if I did not aware that someone else has did a new change to the same file, even though they could be merged.

Comment: To get merge in changes from a particular commit you can use Git Cherry Pick http://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Using_Git_Cherry_Pick

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to make sure my patch will produce "my own" changes compared with my original fileA if I did not aware that someone else has did a new change to the same file,

That means master could be fast-forwarded to topic, since topic would have added new commits, while master would have not:

You can test if it is the case, by trying first a:

```
git checkout topic git merge --ff-only master
```

Then you can merge topic to master (trivial merge).

If you want only to test:

```
    git checkout topic git merge --ff-only --no-commit master
```

No need to parse the output: if the command completes, that means the merge will be a fast-forward one.
(`--no-commit` after the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13079395/6309) of the [OP Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1754879/keith))

Comment: Thanks for your editing and answer. I would notice the question format next time:).

Answer (score 0):

currently, I could identify if git is merging different changes in the same file by the git output:
Auto-merging ............

I will use the "git merge --no-commit" to test the output.
That is my workaround solution..